# What is the Little つ? What does it mean?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

We have a school project for Japanese and we have to explain what Little つ means but I can't find the meaning of it anywhere and our teacher won't tell us what it is. Please help!

Comment: OK we got her to tell I'm going to say what it is so I can remember and so other people know.

if you write a word in japanese it makes the letter in front of it go double and when you sya it you say it with a 'hiccup'. idk if you can even understand what i'm saying but at least i do.

Comment: Did you try researching it yourself at all? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination#Japanese

Comment: yeah but i had no idea what it was at all so when i searched it up it didnt come up with anything. just a bunch of japanese websites that i couldnt understand. i used this website so i could get a simple and easy to undersatnd answer not a blunt remark from someone and the answer i didnt want

Comment: I can see how you'd regard my comment as blunt, but I don't understand what you mean by "the answer you didn't want." The article explains what the function of the small つ is in Japanese. It comes up in basic searches for "small tsu japanese" and the like. Stack Exchange is intended to be a resource to assist in your understanding/research rather than just a homework/translation service, so prior research is something that is appreciated in questions.

Answer (score -1):

けっかく(Kekkaku)

がっこう(Gakkou)

いって（Itte)

the 促音(small tsu) creates “double consonants”.

Comment: I didn't vote it down, but I would advise looking at the guidelines for answers. The goal is to provide the best and most complete answers possible, and this answer doesn't really explain much.